# Oracle sql --SUbquery writing discrepancies

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables table 1 and table 2 with common column being `lead_no`

Now i want to display data from table 1

On condition that if months difference is 6 then display column name as 6,  If the month difference is 
5 then the coumn name goes as 5 and  so on upto month difference equal to 1.  Interestingly enough , the column values  should be the count of no of rows for that particular column name fetched from table 2 based on where some where conditions . I will list that conditions at the end.

**months_diff is the difference b/w SYSDATE and `reported_date` column of table2 .**

`Where conditions`

```
SELECT  col1 as 1  , col2 as 2, col 3 as ... col6 as 6 
  FROM   table1 a
 WHERE   lead_no not in   (SELECT   LEAD_NO FROM table2 
and  RPTCODE=101 and
round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE)) NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
)
```

);

The main problem lies here is to perform subqueries to display data in the above said format . Please let me know if the problem posted is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for some kind of pivot. since you haven't writen what version you are on try something like this

```
select  sum(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as m1 , 
        sum(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as m2 , 
        sum(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as m3 , 
        sum(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as m4 , 
        sum(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as m5 , 
        sum(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as m6 , 
        count(*) as m_all
from    table1 a , table2 b
where   a.lead_no = b.lead_no
and     rptcode <> 101
```

I coulden't understand on what to group by but you can add it in.

Comment: Oracle 11g .  ` count(case when round(months_between(sysdate,reported_date)) == 1 then 1 else 0 end) as m1` will reurn count (1) . I want the count of all rows in tab1 where my month difference turns out to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  sum(CASE round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 1  
, sum(CASE round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 2  
, sum(CASE round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 3  
, sum(CASE round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 4  
, sum(CASE round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 5  
, sum(CASE round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 6  
  FROM   table1 a
WHERE   lead_no not in   (SELECT   LEAD_NO 
                          FROM table2 
                          WHERE
                            RPTCODE=101 
                          and round(months_between(sysdate,REPORTED_DATE)) NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
                         )
;
```